# The app requested an invalid permission

Tags: permissions, settings, facebook-apps

One of the users of our FB application let us know that there were some issues with our application on the 'users' side when they tried to update the app settings via Account Settings > App Settings. When selecting to edit your settings for application, the following error is displayed:

**"The app requested an invalid permission."**

My first thought was to check what my permissions where, and they all were valid! (see below):

> user_photos friends_photos read_stream publish_stream user_likes
>   user_location friends_likes friends_hometown user_birthday
>   friends_birthday friends_checkins user_status friends_status
>   friends_education_history

Anyone ever experience this? I wasn't able to find anything on the interwebs

Answer (score 1):

Yes! But only with one app. I access this from my iPhone through Facebook. I tried to reset my phone, but that didn't fix it. I tried to delete the app and reinstall, but that also didn't work. So I tried to reset the permission and ended up removing it once the message came through.

Then I tried to reinstall - all my friends are still gone and it says my Facebook is logged in but it's just not working as it was! And no sorry, I don't have any fix Yet, but I'm determined!

Comment: Thanks, I ended having to delete the app and remake it, not a great solution if you have a lot of users... they all would have to re-authenticate with your app.